# What is the name of the property of viruses that can go dormant in the host for 30 years?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, microbiology, immunology, virus

The [Varicella zoster virus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicella_zoster_virus) causes chickenpox in children and [shingles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingles) in adults.

It appears after the initial infection, it can go dormant in the nerve, and reactivate itself decades later.

My question is: **What is the name of the property of viruses that can go dormant in the host for 30 years?**

Comment: What do you mean with property? The place, where these viruses hide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know dormancy in viruses like the above stated chicken pox virus is known as [virus latency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus_latency) which wikipedia defines as:

> The ability of a pathogenic virus to lie dormant (latent) within a cell, denoted as the lysogenic part of the viral life cycle.